# Best way to debug NavigationService.GoBack() problems?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, navigation, windows-phone-7.1

I have a Windows Phone 7.5 application which uses the **NavigationService.GoBack()** method to transition between the main page (MainPage.xaml, a PhoneApplicationPage) and a secondary page (Views/ModelLoad.xaml, a PhoneApplicationPage hosting a Panorama control inside the main Grid).

I successfully navigate from the MainPage.xaml to the ModelLoad.xaml page. Once the model is loaded in ModelLoad.xaml (using the Live Connect SDK), I call

```
this.NavigationService.GoBack();
```

I can set a breakpoint in the callback for **NavigationService.Navigating()** and notice that it **is being called**. However, afterwards **nothing else happens**, no NavigationFailed event is raised, and the UI doesn't change. The same happens if I specify a Uri of a page that doesn't exist.

I have tried to use

```
if (NavigationService.CanGoBack) this.Dispatcher(() => NavigationService.GoBack());
```

but that didn't show any different behavior.

Is there a way to **debug this problem** to find out why the navigation is not happening?

**Update:** It appears to be related to threading and focus. Navigate is being called from  a callback after downloading a file from SkyDrive using the **Live Connect SDK**. If I add a button to this page and call NavigationService.GoBack() in the click event handler the UI successfully navigates back to the previous page.

Comment: Where did you try to call the NavigationService.GoBack() the first time?

Comment: The instance of the NavigationService that the callback is using, where did it get that from? Is it the instance of the NavigationService that was passed to the callback from ModelLoad.xaml. Do you have a simple repro app?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call it from inside a Page instance (which has a NavigationService and context), or alternatively invoke it using the CurrentFrame member if you're calling it from your App.